# Erro cURL no pagamento Cielo

Tags: libcurl, woocommerce, ssl

Boa tarde, estou tentando implementar a forma de pagamento da Cielo no woocommerce (plugin https://github.com/greguly/cielo-woocommerce/). Quando tento fazer uma compra em modo de produção aparece o seguinte erro de log:

```
Novo erro: 11-12-2019 @ 15:32:16 - Requesting a transaction for order 13657 with the follow data: WC_Cielo_XML Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[id] => 13657-1573583536
[versao] => 1.3.0
)

[dados-pedido] => WC_Cielo_XML Object
(
[numero] => 13657
[valor] => 56879
[moeda] => 986
[data-hora] => 2019-11-12T15:23:54
[idioma] => PT
)

[forma-pagamento] => WC_Cielo_XML Object
(
[bandeira] => visa
[produto] => 1
[parcelas] => 1
)

[url-retorno] => WC_Cielo_XML Object
(
)

[autorizar] => 3
[capturar] => true
[gerar-token] => false
)

11-12-2019 @ 15:32:16 - An error occurred while requesting the transaction: WP_Error Object
(
[errors] => Array
(
[http_request_failed] => Array
(
[0] => cURL error 52: Empty reply from server
)

)

[error_data] => Array
(
)

)
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

você possivelmente está tentando usar o plugin do `WooCommerce` que foi desenvolvido para funcionar com a versão `1.5` da `API` da Cielo.

Se você iniciou o processo de homologação há pouco tempo, você recebeu as chaves (`Merchant ID` e `token`, se não me engano) da versão 3.0.

Os problemas:

1- É possível conseguir liberação pra API 1.5 ainda, mas depende de cada caso. No forum de suporte do WP tem algumas dicas.

2- Mesmo que você consiga, a Cielo está ameaçando desligar a API 1.5 em maio/2018

3- Existe uma opção paga (google: `woocommerce cielo 3.0), mas algumas pessoas falaram que tem qualidade inferior`

Comment: Olá, o plugin já esta atualizado, tanto que aparece o Merchant ID e a chave de acesso. Na versão 1.5 era apenas necessária o Merchant. Tem mais pessoas com esse problema porém ninguém sabe o que pode ser, tanto que estou constantemente falando com o suporte de hospedagem do site para tentar um auxilio porém eles também não sabem o que pode ser.